# IOS prepareForSegue using custom tableview cell

Tags: ios, uitableview

i created a .xib with my custom cell that I'm using on one of my tableviewcontroller in my storyboard.

In the storyboard, I linked the current tableview with another tableview with a push segue. (when the user click on one of the cell, he has a new view).

The problem is, I don't understand, how to "link" this segue, with my CUSTOM cell ?

I'm loading my custom cell like that :

```
static NSString *simpleTableIdentifier = @"cellCustom";

cellCustomView *cell = (cellCustomView *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];

if (cell == nil) {
    NSArray *nib = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"cellCustom" owner:self options:nil];
    cell = [nib objectAtIndex:0];
}
```

and when I try to implement the method :

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
    NSLog(@"test"); 
}
```

I've nothing, because according me, I missed something to do with my custom cell, and the segue of my storyboard, but I don't understand how it works :/

thx,

Answer (score 0):

Did you try this?

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"MySegue"
                              sender:self];
}
```

This method belong in whichever class contains the tableView. Make sure that the tableView's delegate is equal to self in that class. If you're using a storyboard, control-drag this view to whichever view you want to segue to. Click on that segue, and change its identifier to "MySegue" or whatever you want, as long as its the same in your code.

Comment: in my storyboard, in link the tableview with my other view, and i set an identifier on the segue yes. But, I think I need to do other thing when I use custom cell from xib.

Comment: Ok, your answer is a nice solution, but I don't understand. Why method prepareForSegue doesn't work ?

Comment: @deveLost `prepareForSegue` doesn't initialize a segue. It's called whenever a segue is performed (i.e. right after you use `self performSegueWithIdentifier:sender:`) The point of `prepareForSegue` is to do stuff like pass an object to the destination view controller in the segue.

Comment: mhh, but in my case, I want to pass an object to the destination VC.

Comment: @deveLost Don't forget to accept the answer if it worked for you.

Comment: @deveLost The more customary way to do this is by connecting the segue from the cell (not the controller) to the next controller. If you do that (or that's the way you already have it set up), then you don't need to call performSegueWithIdentifier:sender:, and you shouldn't need to implement didSelectRowAtIndexPath at all.

Comment: @rdelmar You're right, but I've found that sometimes you need this approach in order to pass data from the selected cell forward. Otherwise the segue is called before anything in `didSelectRowAtIndexPath`

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following approach

Control + Drag from your cell to next view controller to setup a segue called "showDetail", that you want to show on clicking tableview cell.

and in your view controller

if you have nsarray such as

```
NSArray *names = @[@"Apple", @"Google", @"Microsoft"];
```

and you want to pass the array value based on the selected table row cell index, you can as follows

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
   if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"showDetail"]) 
   {
        NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow];
        NSString *name = _names[indexPath.row]; 

        // For explanation sake, I am assuming name as property defined 
        // in your destination view controller
        [[segue destinationViewController] setName:name];  
    }
}
```

Comment: hi, thx for help, the answer below yours helped me ^^ but thx :)